# How to submit multiple checkbox value on FormGroup angular

Tags: angularjs, formgroups

I am new to FormGroup, so I guess I making some very silly mistakes, but I am not able to figure out where.

I have designed this below UI:

[image]

Now, as it can be seen, there are 3 checkboxes under `Select Server Option`. So, what I want is on click of the Download button, to submit the values of the checkbox.

What I have tried till now is as shown here:

```
   this.systemlogsform = this.fb.group({
          logtype: ['installlogs', Validators.required],
          servers: [[], Validators.required]
        });

getServiceListData(type) {
    this.nodeList = [];
    this.apiservice.getClusterInfo()
      .subscribe(data => {
        if (Array.isArray(data.NodeList)) {
          this.nodeList = data.NodeList;
        } else {
          this.nodeList.push(data.NodeList);
        }

  })
}
```

The below is the html code:

```
<div class="large-12 small-12 medium-12" *ngIf="systemlogsform.value.logtype==='installlogs'">
          <div>
            <label class="col-md-12 md-padding--s md-padding__left--l md-padding__top--s" for="" formGroupName="systemService"><strong>
                Select Server Option
              </strong></label>
            <div
              class="col-md-3"
              *ngFor="let node of nodeList; let j=index;"
            >
           
                <md-checkbox
                style="padding-left:45px;"
                name="TDG"
                value="{{node.FQDN}}"
                label="{{node.FQDN}}"
                htmlId="{{node.HostName}}"
                [formControl]="node"
                [formControlName]="j">
                </md-checkbox>
               
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The checkbox values will be coming from an api call. So, I can not hard code the values in the form group.

**1)** So, how do I submit multiple values of the checkbox if more than 1 of them are clicked.

**2)** Also, I am facing issue in retrieving the value of the checkbox, can someone please help me with this.